# Show that a graph with $n$ vertices and $n + 2$ edges must contain two edge-disjoint circuits.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that a graph with $n$ vertices and $n + 2$ edges must contain two edge-disjoint circuits.

I'm a bit confused by what an edge-disjoint circuit means here.

Comment: "Edge-disjoint" means that you have two circuits with no edges in common.

Comment: *Hint:* Use what you know about trees and the relationship between the number of edges and vertices in a tree.

Comment: Take $G = K_4$, which has 4 vertices and 6 edges, but for any circuit on three vertices, removing it leave a tree (which has no circuits), so this isn't true for $n=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well but this isn't true though. Take $K_4$ and replace each edge by a path with $k+1$ vertices, where $k$ an arbitrarily large integer. This graph has $4+6k$ vertices and $6+6k$ edges.

I got this idea from @B. Mehta 's comment.